# Identify plant and problem, maybe a Sansevieria?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, indoors, fungus, snake-plants

A friend gave me this plant but didn't know what it was. I thought it could be some kind of *Sansevieria*, but I'm not sure.

But the problem is the leaves are getting yellow, and I don't know why. The yellow starts from the top, usually. I already took out the ones that were totally yellow, from top to bottom.

Someone told me that could be fungus but I don't know how to proceed...
I'm currently watering once every two weeks and it's not under direct sunlight.
Does anyone have a clue?

[image: Sansevieria yellow leaves]
[image: Sansevieria yellow leaves]

Answer (score 1):

yes that is a sanseviera plant. They can be damaged by over watering. If you can put your finger about an inch in and it still feels moist you don't need to water. I would hold back on the watering and let it dry out a little and see if this helps.

Comment: thanks!
before coming to my place, I suspect they were not being watered at all, and they were already like this (but with a lot more of yellow leaves that i took out).

I've stopped watering 1 and 1/2 week ago. it is greener but the yellow is still growing...

Comment: You could cut the leaves back to green, it will mean you have half a leaf but better than a yellowing one?